# Ubuntu 14.04 unable to install any application : 'grub-common': Input/output error

Tags: dpkg

I am unable to install any app from software center or terminal, getting the following error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 reading files list for package 'grub-common': Input/output error
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I have tried many things but they didn't work.

Comment: What does `dmesg` say? An I/O error could indicate a failing drive.

Comment: i am new to linux world, didnt understand what dmesg is ... can you guide step by step